# Python is slow using Windows

Tags: php, python, apache, python-embedding

Yesterday I started with Python to see power of this language and to try learn something new. I know to program in PHP.

I downloaded Python from [this link](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and I extracted it to XAMPP folder.

It works, but too slowly if we compare it with PHP

Watch [this video](http://sendvid.com/pch5aaqb) where you can see POST form in both languages(py and php) how slow is Python.

Here you can see my files:

**index.php** and **say.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo "<html><head><title>PHP</title></head><body><h1>Say something! :D</h1><form action='say.php' method='POST'><input name='say' placeholder='your name'> <input name='to'> <button>And send my greetings</button></form></body></html>";
?>
```

.

```
<?php
$say = htmlspecialchars($_POST['say']);
$to  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['to']);
echo  $say, ': ', $to;
echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){location.href='index.php'},2000)</script>";
?>
```

**index.py** and **say.py**

```
#!/python/python.exe

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print ("""
<html><head><title>Python</title></head><body><h1>Say something! :D</h1><form action="say.py" method="POST"><input name="say" placeholder="your name"> <input name="to"> <button>And send my greetings</button></form></body></html>
""")
```

.

```
#!/python/python.exe

import html
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
say  = html.escape(form["say"].value);
to   = html.escape(form["to"].value);

print(say, ": ", to)
print("""
<script>setTimeout(function(){location.href='index.py'},2000)</script>
""")
```

Why Python isnt faster than PHP? Something missed? Because of Windows? Or ... Something that I dont understand now?

Comment: Your video demonstrates nothing, I'm afraid. Please use a proper benchmark, like `ab` or jmeter.

Answer (score 3):

You are using CGI for the Python integration. CGI is *slow*. Each request requires a new process to be spun up, all HTTP data to be converted to strings sent over stdin to the process, then Python has to compile and run your code (as it is a script, not an imported module), and then the response has to be read from stdout and parsed before sending on to the browser.

PHP on the other hand is running right in webserver process as a plugin. Very little processing has to take place before PHP is called, no new process needs to be created, and the output from PHP goes back to the browser almost unaltered.

Use a [WSGI server](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) instead if you want to make a fairer comparison.